# Undervoltage with 5V 5A PS

Tags: power, power-supply, pi-3a+

I know this is a subject that is exaustive and at risk of sounding ad nauseam I have to ask because I have no solutions.  My pi is reporting undervoltage.  I haven't ran into this since using a Pi1 model B+ >.<

This Pi is not overclocked.

This Pi uses the DSI camera and display ports; there is nothing else connected.

This Pi runs octoprint and utilizes VNC and Desktop.  Ultimately it will display octoprint full time.

No other features are turned on in `raspi-config`.

This power supply is new, but identical to my other Pi setups.  Monitoring voltage I supply a constant unfluctuating 5.1V.  From reboot to idle, it doesn't budge more than 0.02V.  I have the supply power running to pins 2(+) and 14 (-).  Pins 4(+) and 6(+) are supplying power to the Pi Touch Display.  Pins 3(SDA) and 5(SCL) are touchscreen communications.

```
pi@mk4-octopi-pi3:~ $ \
> for id in core sdram_c sdram_i sdram_p ; do \
>     echo -e "$id:\t$(vcgencmd measure_volts $id)" ; \
> done
core:   volt=1.2000V
sdram_c:        volt=1.2500V
sdram_i:        volt=1.2500V
sdram_p:        volt=1.2250V

pi@mk4-octopi-pi3:~ $ vcgencmd get_config int
aphy_params_current=819
arm_freq=1400
arm_freq_min=600
audio_pwm_mode=514
camera_auto_detect=-1
config_hdmi_boost=5
core_freq=400
desired_osc_freq=0x331df0
desired_osc_freq_boost=0x3c45b0
disable_commandline_tags=2
disable_l2cache=1
disable_overscan=1
display_auto_detect=1
display_default_lcd=1
display_hdmi_rotate=-1
display_lcd_rotate=-1
dphy_params_current=547
dvfs=3
enable_tvout=1
force_eeprom_read=1
force_pwm_open=1
framebuffer_ignore_alpha=1
framebuffer_swap=1
gpu_freq=300
init_uart_clock=0x2dc6c00
lcd_framerate=60
max_framebuffers=2
over_voltage_avs=31250
over_voltage_avs_boost=0x2191c
pause_burst_frames=1
program_serial_random=1
sdram_freq=450
total_mem=512
hdmi_force_cec_address:0=65535
hdmi_force_cec_address:1=65535
hdmi_pixel_freq_limit:0=0x9a7ec80
```

Anyone have ideas as to why I'm getting this undervoltage?  The only thing I can think of to try next is power the display directly from the power supply instead of utilizing the pins on the pi - but that's extremely unlikely to be the problem and as I've said I have several identical setups that don't have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate answering my own thread but it may help someone else.

In an effort to solve the problem, as stated in the OP, I tried isolating the power to the display instead of powering it through the Pi.  While doing that, I found the 0V wire kind of broke apart when I was loosening up the terminal.  So I replaced that wire as well as isolating the display power and it worked.  If I had to take an educated guess, the frayed 0V wire was the actual problem.

Comment: Why don't you just delete the answer and question. They just add to the clutter on this site as add no value.

Comment: Because it may help someone else running into the same or a similar issue.  That is, after all, why these exchanges exist.